# Best way to make a RegExp that returns 2 initials of a name?

Tags: javascript, regex, avatar

I was trying to make a RegExp with the following expected results:

```
Input: James Cameron
Expected: JC

Input: James cameron
Expected: JC

Input: James
Expected: JA

Input: James Francis Cameron
Expected: JF
```

I gave up and ended using the following JS code:

```js
function initials(name) {
    return name.toUpperCase().split(/\s+/g).map((s, _i, arr) => (arr.length > 1 ? s[0] : s[0] + s[1])).reduce((a, b) => a + b).substring(0,2);
}
```

Making two separated regular expressions was also easy (for example: `name.replace(/^\s*([a-z]).+?\s+([a-z]).*$/, '$1$2')`)

However i understand it should be a way to fulfill this using only one RegExp.

---

**UPDATE**: Later on, I had one more test-string. The accepted answer didn't worked for it: `James Francis Cameron` as the expected result was `JF`.

I solved it by using the following regex, and `replace` with `$1$2$3`:

```js
^\s*(\S)(?:.+?\s(\S)|(\S)).*$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
.replace(/^(\S{2})\S*$|(?:^|\s*)(\S)\S*\s*/g, '$1$2').toUpperCase()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XrPxt5/2) and the JavaScript demo:

```js
const initials = (name, regex) => name.replace(regex, '$1$2').toUpperCase()

const arr = ['Elon Musk','Elon musk','Elon'];
const rex = /^(\S{2})\S*$|(?:^|\s*)(\S)\S*\s*/g;
arr.forEach( x => console.log(x, "=>", initials(x, rex)) );
```

**Regex details**

- `^(\S{2})\S*$` - start of string (`^`), any 2 non-whitespace characters captured in Group 1 (see `(\S{2})`, later referenced to with `$1`), and then any 0 or more non-whitespace chars (`\S*`) up to the end of string (`$`)
- `|` - or
- `(?:^|\s*)(\S)\S*\s*` - start of string or 0 or more whitespaces (`(?:^|\s*)`), then one non-whitespace char captured into Group 2 (see `(\S)`, later referenced with `$2`), and then 0+ non-whitespaces followed with 0+ whitespaces.

Comment: Later on, I had one more test-string: `Elon Reeve Musk` with expected result `ER`. Today, I finally took the time to understand your RegExp, so thank you so much again. I solved my last test-string with the following: `^\s*(\S)(?:.+?\s(\S)|(\S)).*$`  and replace to this `$1$2$3`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a not that pretty solution:

```js
function initials(name) {
    return (name.match(/^(\w)\w*\s+(\w)|^(\w)(\w)\w*$/) || []).slice(1, 5).filter(v => v).join("").toUpperCase();
}
```